# Getting net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE error while running Ionic5 app on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic5

I am trying to run Ionic 5 app on device using command *ionic cordova run android -l*
But I am getting following error

**Webpage not available
The webpage at http://localhost:8100/ could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE**

Please help.